# PHP - FTP Server - Unable to switch to newly created directory (sometimes!)

Tags: php, linux, ftp

**What I am trying to do**

- Connect to FTP server
- Create new directories
- Upload file into one of those new directories

**What's going wrong?**

Ok, so there is nothing wrong with the ftp connection, I am logging in with the credentials, switching to the relevant starting directory, which in this case is a directory on the server called "test".

At the start, this "test" directory is empty, as I just created it.

What I am then doing is taking a file from my local machine and attempting to upload that the remote path `test/Folder1/Sub1/Sub2/Myfile.txt` on the server.

To do this, I first split the path by "/" and check to see if I can switch to each of those directories, and if I can't, then I create them:

(You'll have to excuse the debugging dumps in the code)

```
// Split the path by directories and try and create all of them if they don't exist
    $workingDir = $this->dir;
    $newPath = str_replace($this->dir, "", $path);
    $split = array_filter( explode("/", $newPath) );

    if ($split)
    {
        foreach($split as $dir)
        {

            // Can we change to it?
            if (!@ftp_chdir($this->conn, $workingDir . '/' . $dir)){

                // Try and make the directory
                if (!@ftp_mkdir($this->conn, $workingDir . '/' . $dir)){
                    var_dump("failed to make: " .$workingDir . '/' . $dir );
                    return false;
                }

                // Set the permissions to the default
                $this->chmod = 0777;
                ftp_chmod($this->conn, $this->chmod, $workingDir . '/' . $dir);
                var_dump("Successfully made directory: " . $workingDir . '/' . $dir . " with permissions: " . $this->chmod);

            }

            $workingDir .= '/' . $dir;

        }
    }
```

This works fine, and I get the output of:

```
'Successfully made directory: /home/conn/test/Folder1 with permissions: 511' (length=74)
'Successfully made directory: /home/conn/test/Folder1/Sub1 with permissions: 511' (length=79)
'Successfully made directory: /home/conn/test/Folder1/Sub1/Sub2 with permissions: 511' (length=84)
```

If i `exit` at this point I can confirm the directories now exist on the remote server, with permissions of 0777

Next bit is to do the file upload into the new directory:

```
var_dump("Use this new name: {$newName}");

    $filename = (($newName) ? $newName : $file->getFileName());
        var_dump("working in remote directory: {$this->dir}");
        var_dump("upload to remote: {$filename}, from: {$file->getFullPath()}");

        // Change to that directory?
        $split = explode("/", $filename);
        $realFileName = array_pop($split);
        $filedir = implode("/", $split);
        var_dump("calling ftp_chdir() to : {$filedir}");


        if (!@ftp_chdir($this->conn, $filedir)){
            var_dump("couldn't change to {$filedir}");
            return false;
        };

        var_dump( ftp_pwd($this->conn) );
        var_dump("actual file name: " . $realFileName);

    return ftp_put($this->conn, $realFileName, $file->getFullPath(), FTP_BINARY);
```

And again, this works fine. I get all the expected dumps:

```
  C:\Ampps\www\duckfusioncore\sys\lib\helpers\datastore\stores\FTPStore.php:121:string 'Use this new name: Folder1/Sub1/Sub2/Myfile.txt' (length=47)
C:\Ampps\www\duckfusioncore\sys\lib\helpers\datastore\stores\FTPStore.php:124:string 'working in remote directory: /home/conn/test' (length=44)
C:\Ampps\www\duckfusioncore\sys\lib\helpers\datastore\stores\FTPStore.php:125:string 'upload to remote: Folder1/Sub1/Sub2/Myfile.txt, from: C:\Ampps\www\duckfusioncore\app\lotto\tmp\tmp-nsEMH1RsDX' (length=110)
C:\Ampps\www\duckfusioncore\sys\lib\helpers\datastore\stores\FTPStore.php:131:string 'calling ftp_chdir() to : Folder1/Sub1/Sub2' (length=42)
C:\Ampps\www\duckfusioncore\sys\lib\helpers\datastore\stores\FTPStore.php:139:string '/home/conn/test/Folder1/Sub1/Sub2' (length=33)
C:\Ampps\www\duckfusioncore\sys\lib\helpers\datastore\stores\FTPStore.php:140:string 'actual file name: Myfile.txt' (length=28)
C:\Ampps\www\duckfusioncore\app\lotto\controllers\IndexController.php:28:boolean true
```

All the directories exist. The file is uploaded. All is well.

Except, if I now change the path I want to upload to and change toa new sub directory, which doesn't yet exist, e.g: `Folder1/Sub1/NewSub/Myfile.txt`

This is where it all goes wrong.

So the script runs through the create directory part again, and it successfully creates the new directory "NewSub", with the exact same permissions as before, and I can confirm that the directory exists on the remote server.

Except now when we get to the upload part, even though the directory exists, and this worked previously as we saw, it is unable to change to that new directory:

```
    C:\Ampps\www\duckfusioncore\sys\lib\helpers\datastore\stores\FTPStore.php:121:string 'Use this new name: Folder1/Sub1/NewSub/Myfile.txt' (length=49)
C:\Ampps\www\duckfusioncore\sys\lib\helpers\datastore\stores\FTPStore.php:124:string 'working in remote directory: /home/conn/test' (length=44)
C:\Ampps\www\duckfusioncore\sys\lib\helpers\datastore\stores\FTPStore.php:125:string 'upload to remote: Folder1/Sub1/NewSub/Myfile.txt, from: C:\Ampps\www\duckfusioncore\app\lotto\tmp\tmp-XJYdx8eduL' (length=112)
C:\Ampps\www\duckfusioncore\sys\lib\helpers\datastore\stores\FTPStore.php:131:string 'calling ftp_chdir() to : Folder1/Sub1/NewSub' (length=44)
C:\Ampps\www\duckfusioncore\sys\lib\helpers\datastore\stores\FTPStore.php:135:string 'couldn't change to Folder1/Sub1/NewSub' (length=38)
C:\Ampps\www\duckfusioncore\app\lotto\controllers\IndexController.php:28:boolean false
```

The directory 100% exists. And it has the same 0777 permissions as the other ones.

[image: it exists]

I'm just very confused as to why it is unable to switch to the directory, when it defintely exists and it has the same permissions as the other directories, which it had no problem switching to before...

Has anyone got any clue what might be the problem? Is there any extra debugging I can do on the ftp_chdir() function call to see if it gives me a reason?

Thanks.

Comment: Please set the folder permission. and then check

Comment: Pass to `ftp_chdir` absolute path, not relative. I think, on first upload you change dir, and in second upload you attempt change dir relative to first created directory. Example (numbers is attempt numbers): 1. Folder1/Sub1 2. Folder1/Sub1/Folder1/NewSub

Comment: @maximkou that seems to have worked, thanks. If you want to add it as an answer i can accept it, for the internet points.